# C error: "initializer element is not constant" with &, works with +

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

With GCC I get the "initializer element is not constant" error for the second line of the following code:

```
uint8_t gBuffer[512 + 4]; /* Data buffer */
uint8_t* gAlignedBuffer = (uint8_t*)(((uint32_t)gBuffer + 4) & 0xFFFFFFFCU);   /* Align buffer to 4-byte boundary */
```

However if I change
**&** 0xFFFFFFFCU
to 
**+** 0xFFFFFFFCU
the code compiles ok:

```
uint8_t gBuffer[512 + 4]; /* Data buffer */
uint8_t* gAlignedBuffer = (uint8_t*)(((uint32_t)gBuffer + 4) + 0xFFFFFFFCU);   /* Align buffer to 4-byte boundary */
```

Why is this?

Comment: both lines give the same error for me i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Comment: You should probably mention that your variables are declared with static storage duration, i.e in file scope.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are declaring your variables in file scope. File scope variables have static storage duration and require constant initializers.

While your initializers don't exactly satisfy the most strict and narrow definition of address constant expression (as defined in the languages specification), they might still be supported by your specific compiler. The inconsistency you observe has no real reason to exist though. I'd guess that this is a quirk of that specific compiler.

Comment: Neither of them are constant, yes, but relocations are still allowed in constant initializers (see my answer).

Comment: @Drew McGowen: Well, you are probably talking about a specific platform under a specific set of settings. The language itself prohibits converting pointers to integers in *arithmetic* constant expressions. In a *pointer* constant expression the address of a global array would work fine. But not in *arithmetic* one. So, formally, it is not about relocations.

Comment: @AndreyT: The language does not prohibit converting pointers to integers in constant expressions. It does not require this to be supported, but it permits it. C 2011 6.6 10: “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.”

Comment: This answer is incorrect to state “The inconsistency you observe has no real reason to exist”. The second code sequence can be easily resolved by a compiler in two ways: (1) Recognizing that the additions cancel (in the normal course of expression reduction) and leave the initializer equivalent to `gBuffer`, which is a constant expression. (2) Writing the expression to the assembly or object code as a relocatable expression supported by the underlying software. The first sequence cannot be resolved by either of these means, if the linker does not support relocations with `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Since these variables are file scope, they have static storage, so the behavior has to do with what kind of [relocations](http://web.archive.org/web/20120111052442/http://www.benxos.com/archives/133) your output file format supports (I assume it's ELF).

Basically, in this case, ELF objects support adding any number to an unknown address, but not applying a mask (which is basically what the `&` operation does). You will need to move the second statement into a function.

Comment: I agree. FYI, there is no net addition to the address; +4 and +0xFFFFFFFCU are inverses, so the net effect is `uint8_t* gAlignedBuffer = gBuffer;` (assuming `unsigned int` is 32 bit).

Comment: Good catch; I didn't even think about that.

Comment: Correct, output file is ELF. You can replace the 0xFFFFFFFC with e.g. 1 and the same result occurs, it works with + , does not work with &.
BTW, the CodeWarrior ARM Cortex M compiler acts in the same way as GCC for ARM Cortex M.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score -2):

My suspicions is that something is happening with the operator precedence here. & is higher precedendce than + .

Comment: This answer is incorrect because I can reproduce this error on my own compiler, while only using &